# hyperlinks in children (d3.js objects) in a collapsible force layout

Tags: hyperlink, d3.js, force-layout

I have no idea how to program in d3.js, and I am aware that my question might be simple or even stupid. I am trying to modify this visualization http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130, by adding hyperlinks to the last objects of the hierarchy (the orange ones). I understand that there is something happening already (collapsing, expanding) when someone clicks on the parent elements, but the children (the last ones) don't seem to perform a particular action on the click, is it possible to add a hyperlink there?

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
  root = json;
  update();
});

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
      : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
      : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}

</script>
```

And this is the json:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like that "AspectRatioBanker" could take me to www.aspectratiobanker.com, for example. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options here.

1. Including an [`a` tag in the SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links) itself.
2. Handle the action in the click handler.

The first option is a better use, IMO, since it is more semantic and allows the user to see that the node is an link, to right click and copy web address and open it in a new page etc.

However, the second one would require the least change to the program:

```
// Toggle children on click.

var urlMap = {
    'AspectRatioBanker': 'http://www.google.com'
    // ... more name -> URL mappings
};

function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  } else {
    // This was a leaf node, so redirect.
    window.location = urlMap[d.name];
  }
  update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that's the way I phrased the question, and I already have an answer, but, is there a way to link the objects to a url different that the name? Let's say, AspectRadioBanker to google.com, for example?

Comment: @Ernesto Updated the answer with a URLmap dictionary.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I managed (don't ask me how) to solve the issue and to find a way to display the emerging windows as pop-ups using this:
 
    window.open(d.url, 'popUpWindow','height=600,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
  }
  update();
}

I am so proud of myself (hehehe)... Now I am trying to break the lines of the names because they are too long.